# Does the latest version of opencv have dlib included in it

Tags: opencv, dlib

Just want to make sure if the latest version of opencv have dlib

Answer (score 1):

No, those are separate libraries .

Dlib has functions that expect Opencv `cv::Mat` so you can use them as an interface.